# Ĉu "ĉi" sen tabelvorto estas akceptata?

Tags: word-usage

Mia instrulibro instruis al mi ke oni povas meti "ĉi" apud la tabelvortojn por montri proksimecon. Tamen mi fojfoje vidas tiun vorton solan sen tabelvorto. Ekzemple:

> Verŝajne neniu homo senkulpas pri ĉio en ĉi mondo

Kaj ankaŭ kelkfoje ĝi estas uzata en kunmetita vorto:

> Feliĉe la aŭtomata klimatizado ĉi-vagone funkciis

(ambaŭ ekzemploj estas de Skabio de Sten Johansson)

Ĉu tiuj uzoj de la vorto estas polemikaj aŭ ĉu ili estas ĝenerale akceptitaj? Ĉu Zamenhof uzis ĝin tiel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La prefikseca uzo de "ĉi" kiel en "ĉivagone" aŭ "ĉi-semajne" estas tute normala kaj plene rekomendinda. [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html#i-h6f) bone klarigas ĉi tiun uzon.

La uzo de "ĉi" en la senco de "ĉi tiu" kiel memstara vorto aperas relative ofte en poezia lingvaĵo, sed nur malofte ekster ĝi. Mi malrekomendus ĝian uzadon ekster poezio.

Answer (score 4):

Mi pensas ke jes. Almenaŭ mi multfoje vidis ĝin en tiaj adverboj. Ekzemple:
ĉi-semajne
ĉi-foje
ĉi-jare

Comment: Mi pensas, ke “ĉi mondo” ja estas malĝusta. Estu “ĉi tiu mondo” aŭ “tiu ĉi mondo”.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Prave! Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html#i-h6f): *Rimarku, ke kunmetaĵoj kun prefikseca ĉi ĉiam havas A-finaĵon aŭ E-finaĵon. O-vortoj kun prefikseca ĉi ne eblas.*

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev ĉi tiu kazo ne estas prefikseca, la “ĉi” estas aparta vorto. PMEG aparta parolas pri tiu okazo sub “Memstara ĉi”. Li ne rekte diras ke ĝi estas erara, sed nur diras “iuj opinias, ke memstara ĉi anstataŭ ĉi tiu(j) estas evitinda (krom eble en poezio)”.