# Can "ĉi" be used as a postposition?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

One can say "ĉi tiel", or "tiel ĉi".

It's also common to use "ĉi" on its own, mentioned in [this PMEG page](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html) and also on the PIV entry for "ĉi". An example of this appearing on both pages is "ĉi ne estas akvo".

I'm looking at the PIV entry for "ĉi", and I see this:

> Rim. «pro belsoneco ordinare estas preferinde starigi la ĉi antaŭ la montra vorto» (Z.).

"montra vorto" here is not specified as being a table word, though maybe that's what *montra vorto* refers to and I'm unaware.

But doesn't this mean ĉi could potentially appear after a non-table word as a postposition, perhaps in poetry since it would likely sound odd and perhaps be confusing in everyday speech?

An example might be:

> Mi ŝatas la domon ĉi!

Which might mean either: *Mi ŝatas ĉi domon* or *Mi ŝatas la domon ĉi tie.*

> Mia frato estas la viro ĉi.

Again, this could be: *Mia frato estas ĉi viro* or *Mia frato estas la viro ĉi tie.*

These examples carry some ambiguity, but in poetry that can be desirable, and it's not always a problem in day to day conversation, either. To me both statements seem easily clarified by context. So, is this possible? Is there any precedent for this?

Comment: Also, I don't know if "ĉi" fits the definition of a preposition OR a postposition, maybe it's just a particle, but I wasn't sure what other word to use to concisely convey what I mean.

Comment: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/499/%C4%88u-%C4%89i-sen-tabelvorto-estas-akceptata That thread is all in Esperanto, but you might find something useful there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing we can say for sure is what *vorto montra* means. The *Ekzercaro de la Fundamento de Esperanto* also mentions *vortojn montrajn.*

*Se ni aldonas la literon “t”, ni ricevas **vortojn montrajn**: tia, tial, tiam, tie, tiel, ties, tio, tiom, tiu.* [...] *Aldonante al la **vortoj montraj** la vorton “ĉi”, ni ricevas montron pli proksiman*

For several reasons, you'll never see *ĉi* by itself after a word. The biggest reason is hinted at in the PMEG article you referenced.

*En tia uzo ĉi transprenis la rolon de tiu(j), kaj fariĝis mem difinilo.*

We discussed the concept of *difinilo* in NASK this summer and Bertilo confirmed my understanding of the matter, which is that *difiniloj* (such as *la*, *tiu*, and in this case *ĉi*) always come before the word they're making definite. When a word that usually acts like a *difinilo* is moved to a different position, we no longer sense the expression as definite.

- mia amiko = my friend (*the* specific friend)
- amiko mia = a friend of mine

Not every speaker makes this distinction, but it happens because *mia* is a *difinilo* and every other *difinilo* in the language comes before the rest of the noun phrase.

I also checked Tekstaro and found 100 sentences that end with *ĉi* -- every one of them was with a form of *ĉio* or a ti-correlative.

As for sentences like *Mi ŝatas la domon ĉi!* these are really exceptions found in poetry or old texts - and as explained in PIV and PMEG *ĉi* in this case means *ĉi tie* and never *ĉi tiu.*